# Error string to float

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code. I am doing a beginer execise. When I run the program

I can put the values, but when I go out of the loop the following error message appears:

```
 a + = float (input ("Enter the product cost"))
```

ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Can someone help me?

Here it goes:

```
e = 0.25
f = 0.18
a = 0.0

while True:
    a += float(input("Enter the product cost:  "))
    if a == "":        
        break

b = a*e
c = a*f
d = a+b+c

print ("tax: " + b)
print ("tips: " + c)
print ( "Total: " + d)
```

Comment: You can do  `a_input=float(input("Enter the product cost: "))`

Answer (score 1):

You are combining two operations on the same line: the input of a string, and the conversion of the string to a `float`. If you enter the empty string to end the program, the conversion to `float` fails with the error message you see; the error contains the string it tried to convert, and it is empty.

Split it into multiple lines:

```
while True:
    inp = input("Enter the product cost:  ")
    if inp == "":        
        break
    a += float(inp)
```

Comment: Isn't `in` a Python keyword? Perhaps rename the variable

Comment: No problem, and great answer!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues:

1. the check for a being an empty string `("")` comes *after* the attempt to add it to the `float` value `a`. You should handle this with an exception to make sure that the input is numerical.
2. If someone doesn't enter an empty or invalid string, ever, then you get stuck in an infinite loop and nothing prints. That's because the indentation of your `b, c, d` calculations and the `prints` is outside of the scope of the `while` loop.

This should do what you want:

```
e = 0.25
f = 0.18
a = 0.0

while True:
    try:
        input_number = float(input("Enter the product cost:  "))
    except ValueError:
        print ("Input is not a valid number")
        break
    a += input_number        
    b = a*e
    c = a*f
    d = a+b+c

    print ("tax: ", b)
    print ("tips: ", c)
    print ( "Total: ", d)
```